# Disable href, do some ajax stuff, re-enable href

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, hyperlink, href

here is the problem :

I have a  tag, when i click on it, my href value makes appear a popup (fancybox),

```
<a class="myIdentifier" href="#myPopup">pop</a>
```

but, when i click on it i have to do some stuff with ajax to update the fields into my popup... before it appears!

```
$("body").on('click','.myIdentifier',function(event){
    //DO SOME AJAX AND FILL MY POPUP FIELDS
});
```

SO this ajax stuff HAS TO be done before the "href" is used to call the popup...

i'm looking for a way to disable my href just for the time i do my jquery function, and then re-enable it to make the popup appear...

Thanks

EDIT / UPDATE ::

Well, thanks for all your answers but, have a look at this :

```
<a class="btn btn-warning editImp" href="#editImpPopup" title="Edit" id="22">EDIT</a>
<a class="btn btn-warning editImp" href="#editImpPopup" title="Edit" id="32">EDIT</a>
<a class="btn btn-warning editImp" href="#editImpPopup" title="Edit" id="44">EDIT</a>
```

preventDefault() does not work... seems like the fancybox does not care about it... event is triggered with href anyway...

i use the jquery.fancybox.js, this is a library, i don't know how to manually call the popup! i think i should turn these a tags into other tag which does not respond to fancybox code, apply my ajax stuff to fill the form, and then "manually generate" a "click on a a tag with href set with "editImpPopup"" ...

But how??

Thanks!

(sorry for my english, this is not my motherlanguage...)

FULL CODE :

HTML (the links that call the popup) :

```
<span class="linkhere">
    <a class="btn btn-warning editImp" href="#editImpPopup" title="Modifier" id="191-150">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </a>
</span>
<span class="linkhere">
    <a class="btn btn-warning editImp" href="#editImpPopup" title="Modifier" id="190-140">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </a>
</span>
```

JS (initialize the fancybox) :

```
$(".editImp").fancybox({
    type    :"inline",
    closeBtn :true
});
```

JS (on.click function where i fill my inputs in my form) :

```
$("body").on('click','.editImp',function(){

    var id=this.id;
    var tab = id.split('-');
    id = tab[0];
    var ets = tab[1];
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : './php/utils/getImpData.php',
        data : {'id':id},
        dataType : 'json',
        error : function(response){
            alert("ERROR GET IMPLANTATION DATA");
        },
        success : function(response){
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            $("#etsEditImp option").removeAttr('selected').filter("[value='"+ets+"']").attr('selected',true);
            $("#stageEditImp option").removeAttr('selected').filter("[value='"+response[0].stage+"']").attr('selected',true);
            $("#downEditImp option").removeAttr('selected').filter("[value='"+response[0].down+"']").attr('selected',true);
            $("#locEditImp option").removeAttr('selected').filter("[value='"+response[0].loc+"']").attr('selected',true);
            $("#nameEditImp").val(response[0].name);
            $("#streetEditImp").val(response[0].street);
            $("#numEditImp").val(response[0].num);
            $("#bEditImp").val(response[0].b);
            $("#prevStage").val(response[0].stage);
            $("#prevDown").val(response[0].down);
            $("#idImp").val(id);
            $("#prevEts").val(ets);
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE 2 :

I try this... :

```
$(".editImp").fancybox({
    type    :"inline",
    closeBtn :true,
    beforeLoad : function(event){
        alert("TEST");
        var id=$(this).id;
        var tab = id.split('-');
        id = tab[0];
        var ets = tab[1];
        $.ajax({
            //...CODE
        });
    },
    onStart : function(){alert("TESTSTART");}
});
```

i get this error : id is undefined !
i can't get the id back into this part?

Comment: @divakar: The `href` is already a hash reference.  And changing it back *after* the click event has been processed won't really do anything...

Comment: You have to manually call fancybox in the complete function for the ajax call

Comment: how do you init fancybox? i would say the best way would be to use `beforeLoad` callback...

Comment: @reyaner `beforeLoad` will not wait for ajax success, will it?

Comment: depends, if you use it sync, then it will...

Comment: @reyaner `async: false` is a bad thing.

Comment: @Regent would you mind to explain why?

Comment: @reyaner because browser UI will hang till Ajax call ends

Comment: @Regent in this case it is a good thing, my browser should NOT display the popup until its inputs are filled with the data i have to get back from ajax;...

Comment: One thing you might try is to not initialize the FancyBox element right away and wait for the click event.  Then on the click event perform your AJAX and in the success handler initialize the FancyBox element.  Similar to the "Manual 1" example here (http://fancybox.net/) but with an AJAX call in the middle.

Comment: @Julo0sS: No, in this case `async:false` is still a bad thing.  Don't block the UI.  Perform UI updates in response to asynchronous operations.

Comment: @David : can't find your example...

Comment: @Regent : with async : changes nothing...

I have select tags into my form, my select do not get updated with the data i get... sometimes yes, sometimes not... think async has to do something with it

Comment: @Julo0sS: It's the first one under the section titled "Examples of manual call".  Look in the source code to see how that element is handled in JavaScript.  And `async:false` doesn't "change nothing."  It blocks the browser.  Never block the UI.  Just because you don't want a particular `div` to show up for a moment doesn't mean you should freeze the UI during that time.

Comment: @Julo0sS take a look at my answer: maybe it will finally be the required one...

Comment: @Regent ... and... where is your answer?

Comment: @Julo0sS David mentioned the problem, so I have redone answer, sorry.

Comment: @Julo0sS: Ok, but what has this changed?  The underlying problem, as I understand it, is still the same.  You initialize a FancyBox when the page loads and display it when an element is clicked.  Instead, I suggest initializing it after the element is clicked in response to the AJAX call.  Or, conversely, not changing the FancyBox usage at all and instead approaching the issue an entirely different way within that "popup" by indicating in its UI that data is still loading.  (Such as overlaying the elements or not displaying them until the AJAX call returns.)

Comment: @David : so, you just mean that my code $('...').fancybox... should be into the success part of the ajax call?

Comment: @Julo0sS: You might need to change some of the FancyBox options to have it display immediately upon initialization, but that's the idea yes.

Comment: @Julo0sS as David said, the underlying is still the same. So you should either initialize fancybox every time as David suggested  or use second click with checking (ajax or popup to trigger) as I have done.

Comment: @David : well... this does not solve the problem, first, if i initialize the fancybox settings for this class (code above) INTO the success of ajax part, this will not trigger anything and it will not show up... but i think that if i trigger a click on the a tag it should be ok (BUT it will trigger the click function again! :/) AND if i do this, it will "initialize" the class as much times as i will click on it...

Comment: @Julo0sS: There is likely some combination of options in the FancyBox initialization which causes it to display upon initialization, since that's what FancyBox does *on their own website*. That's why I said you'd likely have to change some of the options. I make no guarantee that your *existing* code will work in *every possible* situation. As for subsequent clicks, perhaps the FancyBox can be unloaded when it's closed? Or maybe the plugin is smart enough to handle this? Again, *their own example* does exactly this, so clearly it *does* work.

Comment: @David : i found few functions which seem to be useful to me. Like : beforeLoad and onStart, and i can put them into my initialization. But, i have to get my ID back when i call the popup... and, into my initialization i can't get it... i'll paste the code into question... thank you very much for help...

Comment: @Regent : another update...^^ i see an answer from David... no answer from you bro, i don't ignore you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the fact (for example, using class) that element was clicked first time to check whether click is for sending ajax or is for opening popup.

Just to mention: `.always()` is used for testing. If you want to show up popup only on ajax success, it should be `.done()` instead.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tr84b87/6/).

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.myIdentifier').fancybox();

    $("body").on('click', '.myIdentifier', function()
    {
        var thisEl = $(this);
        if (!thisEl.hasClass("js-ajax_done"))
        { 
            $.ajax({ url: "incorrect_url"}).always(function()
            {
                $('#log').append("Ajax is done<br/>");
                $('#myPopup').text("Ajax data");
                thisEl.addClass("js-ajax_done");
                thisEl.click();
            });
            $('#log').append("End of first click (waiting for ajax)<br/>");
            return false;
        }
        $('#log').append("End of second click (ready to open popup)<br/>");
        thisEl.removeClass("js-ajax_done");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="myIdentifier" href="#myPopup">pop1</a>
<a class="myIdentifier" href="#myPopup">pop2</a>
<a class="myIdentifier" href="#myPopup">pop3</a>
<div id="myPopup" style="display: none">Popup</div>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Finally i see it! let's have a look

Comment: @Julo0sS I have actually deleted answer for several minutes to fix bug. Then I undeleted it. Maybe that's why you didn't see it, even though it was posted 58 minutes ago :)

Comment: what's this class "ajax-done"?? i'm tryin to edit your fiddle to compare it with my problem

Comment: @Julo0sS `js-ajax_done` is used as flag. It has no styles or other meanings. Just element's flag.

Comment: can you have a look at "our" fiddle... i'm making mistakes... sry^^ i need these 4 select to get updated before popup launches

Comment: there : http://jsfiddle.net/0tr84b87/6/ ... i need to do it this way, i have to handle id var to make my ajax query BUT now... fancybox does not open oO

Comment: @Julo0sS I will get back in two hours. But as I have already said, the idea is to send ajax request on first click, and to trigger second click on ajax success (after parsing ajax data).

Comment: @Julo0sS I fixed errors in your fiddle and make a lot of comments to help to understand what is going on in code: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tr84b87/35/). It is based on fiddle version 33, not version 34 (I didn't see your version 34 yet).

Comment: @Julo0sS we can still use comments under my answer to handle problems. Yes, it's not fast discussion, but I don't have a lot of free time either. Some no more necessary comments can be deleted to prevent long list of comments. And, by the way, are there any problems left?

Comment: yep, the same problem is still there... looks like the answer is not there.. even if i learned good things with your help... it would really be easier to chat to explain...

Comment: @Julo0sS In StackOverflow comments can be moved to chat. But I still visit site not very often, so I can't answer "every second".

Comment: @Julo0sS You can see [this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61446/discussion-between-regent-and-julo0ss).

Comment: may i move this discussion to chat? the "project" i am in, is kinda huge... so that'll be hard to show you the "real-complete" code... BUT, the fact is that the problem i mention in the fiddle, in the comments below the code, is still the same... the function on the 1st popup i call works fine, the function on the 2nd leaves a select element with NO selected item, and on the 3rd one, leaves 2 select elements with NO selected item... and, these select are different for each popup... :/

Answer (score 1):

Just simply do `event.preventDefault()` and call popup script after you done Ajax.

```
$(document).on('click','.myIdentifier',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    showLoader();
    $.ajax({
       url: $(this).attr('href'),
       success: function(data){
          $('#someStuff').val(data);
          callPopup();
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you know how to call popup?

Comment: @Regent depends on what type of popup. It can be simple `$('#popup').fadeIn()` or `$('#popup').modal('show')`

Comment: Fancybox popup, as mentioned in question.

Comment: @Regent : may we chat somewhere pls?

Answer (score 1):

How/when do you initialize the FancyBox plugin for the target element in the first place?  When the page loads?

Instead, maybe initialize it in response to the AJAX call.  Take a look at the "Manual 1" example [here](http://fancybox.net/).  Note in the page's source that it doesn't initialize the plugin right away, but only after the click event:

```
$("#manual1").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        // options
    });
});
```

You can probably do the same thing in response to an AJAX call using this same structure:

```
$("#yourElement").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        // options
    }).done(function (response) {
        $.fancybox({
            // options
        });
    }).fail(function () {
        // handle error
    });
});
```

Comment: even if you'll say something like "newbie".. i'd ask, how can i do??? may i post my code into my 1st question? but there are many lines... many lines if i have to post my ajax query + my fancybox initializing + my html...

Comment: @Julo0sS: It's unlikely that posting *all* of your code would be particularly helpful.  Though if there's any particular segment of your code which would change or invalidate my answer (or any other answer) then that would be worth including in the question.  What specifically about my answer is unclear?  All I'm doing is handling a click event, performing an AJAX call, and initializing the FancyBox plugin.  You've already done all of these things in your own code, just in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$("body").on('click','.myIdentifier',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //DO SOME AJAX AND FILL MY POPUP FIELDS


    // on ajax success
    callPapup();
```

});

### edit

`$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" )` changed to `callPopup()`;

Comment: It will trigger `#foo` before ajax call return and fields fills

Comment: @Justinas Do you want to add `id="foo"` to mentioned `<a>`?

Comment: Wouldn't `.myIdentifier` also be the same element?  If you trigger the same element's click again, wouldn't it just do this again?

Comment: @David if ID is supposed to be added to same `<a>` - it will, yes.

Comment: @David no it will not... look at my updated question... i have several a tags with same class but different ID... the class is used to trigger the event, the ID is used to get the data with ajax...

Comment: @Julo0sS: Whether it's a class or an id makes no difference.  When you click "element X" you would invoke this handler, which in turn invokes a click on "element X", which in turn invokes this handler, which in turn... It's called an infinite recursion.

Comment: @David : This is the problem i have. My fancybox is called when i click, and i have an event (body).on(click,myClass,function(){}) listening to the click... the data i get from ajax is good, but some fields are NOT updated when i handle the data (the select fields only, but not all), i think it is because popup appears before all ajax stuff is done...

Comment: @Julo0sS: Yes, I understand the problem.  Which is why I've offered a possible solution in another answer.  You might also try approaching the problem in an entirely different way if this doesn't work.  Allow the FancyBox element to show, but internal to that element show that data is still loading.  (With a spinner or some progress indicator perhaps.)

Comment: @David : please have a look at this, this is the question that made me open a new topic here... (sorry in advance for my english) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885239/multiple-update-selected-item-in-list-with-jquery-on-click

Comment: @Julo0sS: How is that question relevant?  Is this question a duplicate of that one?  Admittedly you weren't getting much useful information on that one, if the two questions are indeed asking the same thing then I'd recommend deleting that other one and focusing on this one.

Comment: @David : it is the same problem, but the other one has much more information... (noticed that if there were too much information, nobody takes the time for reading...)

Comment: @Julo0sS: If it's the same problem, please choose one of the two questions and delete the other one.  Otherwise you run the risk of this one being closed as a duplicate of the original, which wouldn't be very helpful to you.